# How to pass a request parameter from one servlet to a other while forwaring

Tags: java, servlets, parameters, forward

There is my goal that I can't achieve for now :

I have one servlet, say 'ReportServlet'. It takes a request parameter, say 'p'.
I can obviously get the parameter by :

```
 request.getParameter("p");
```

The query string in my JSP is :

```
<a href="<c:url value="/report"/>?p=value">report</a>
```

And everythings works fine.

Now : I have another servlet, say 'PreProcessingServlet'. I want to forward PreProcessingServlet to ReportServlet, passing a 'p' parameter which is computed in PreProcessingServlet. I tried :

```
RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/report?p="+value);
rd.forward(request, response);
```

But the parameter 'p' goes in the request's queryString member, not in the parameters.

How can I pass the 'p' parameter, using query parameter in the way that I can retrieve 'p' the same way from the JSP and from the forward.

I don't want to use a request attribute because **I want a unique solution to get the parameter from both a JSP and a forward**.

I guess I'm missing something, but I can't find what !

Comment: If you're forwarding, you don't need to pass the parameters, they are already there, it's the same request object.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You should post that as an answer

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis that's the catch : the parameter are not in the request. it's computed from other source in the PreProcessingServlet. I edit the question

Comment: 'I obviously don't want to use a request attribute.' - why is it so obvious?

Comment: I meant that because I want a unique solution to get the parameter from both a JSP and a forward. I edit the question.

Comment: Clarify how the parameters are computed in the `PreProcessingServlet`. They don't come from the query string?

Comment: Let say 'p' is a id to a database object, `PreProcessingServlet` gets a JSON parameter, stores it as a database object and forward to `ReportServlet` with p has the object's id. But it's just one use case from many.

Comment: Honestly, it doesn't make sense to inject or modify a query string. The client makes the request they want to the URI they want. It's up to the server to handle that given request. Use request attributes. They will be available after a `forward` regardless of what resource you send it to.

Comment: I can understand why you could say that. But, in this case, I'm just trying to avoid somthing like : `if(request.getParameter("p") == null) {String p = request.getAttribute("p")} else {String p = request.getParameter("p")}`. In this design, it does make sense. And BTW, I was curious of understanding, this servlet specific aspect.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When in doubt, always go to the [specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/). In this case, see chapter `9.1.1 Query Strings in Request Dispatcher Paths`

> The `ServletContext` and `ServletRequest` methods that create
>   `RequestDispatcher`  objects using path information **allow the optional
>   attachment of query string  information to the path**. For example, a
>   Developer may obtain a `RequestDispatcher`  by using the following code:
>
> ```
> String path = "/raisins.jsp?orderno=5"; 
> RequestDispatcher rd = context.getRequestDispatcher(path);    
> rd.include(request, response);
> ```
>
> Parameters specified in the query string used to create the
>   `RequestDispatcher` take precedence over other parameters of the same
>   name passed to the included servlet. **The parameters associated with a
>   `RequestDispatcher` are scoped to apply only for  the duration of the
>   include or forward call.**

So you can very well do

```
RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/report?p="+value);
rd.forward(request, response);
```

And the parameter `p` will be available only for `HttpServletRequest` that is given to the resource mapped to handle the specified path, ie. `/report` in this case. If that is a `HttpServlet`, you can then access it with

```
request.getParameter("p");
```

where `request` would be the `HttpServletRequest` method parameter.

When the `forward(..)` call terminates and execution comes back to your `PreProcessingServlet`, the parameter will no longer be available in the local `HttpServletRequest` object.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out this part of the spec. That's what I was looking for. So it _can_ work. I'm going to check this out. Thanks again.

Comment: OK, my bad : It was working just fine... I guess I must have been confused by eclipse debugger inspector or something. Thanks a lot : It helps me take my head out of the bucket :)

Comment: Is it bad practice to pass parameters via the query string used to create the RequestDispatcher?  Or is that acceptable?

Comment: @kerafill I don't think it's bad practice, but you're now passing around information as if it had come from the client. That might be confusing.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes, I agree.  I decided to pass them via setAttribute instead.  My servlet checks for any get/post parameters, then pass the values via setAttribute and forward it to a .jsp view.  The .jsp doesn't check anymore in the param[], but from requestScope[].  It's cleaner that way.  I also don't need to escape any URL coz setAttribute handles nonordinary characters.

Comment: It should be noted that the window.location.search does not get updated with the query parameters. They are only set on the request itself. So you can't just forward or include an HTML page that doesn't have access to the HttpServletRequest itself.